# how to replace text in listview

Tags: android, listview

I need to replace "gold" in Listview

AndroidListView1= "gold" > "goldennnnnnn" AndroidListView2= "gold" > "golderrrrrrrrr"

when i set it in **edittext** then its work!! but when i set it in **List view** then print only 1 item("goldennnnnnn")##
**this.et3.setText(AndroidListView); (edittext work)** but **this.Listview.setText(AndroidListView1);not work**

this is my code ***thanks in advance***

```
ListView listView ;
EditText myTextBox,myOuttext,et3;
Button btn;

ClipboardManager myClipboard;
private Object adapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     myTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     myOuttext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
     btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


     // Get ListView object from xml
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

     // Defined Array values to show in ListView
     String[] values = new String[]
             { "AndroidListView1", 
             "AndroidListView2",
             "AndroidListView3",
             "AndroidListView4",
             "AndroidListView5",
             "AndroidListView6",
             "AndroidListView7",
             "AndroidListView8",
             "AndroidListView9",
             "AndroidListView10",
             "AndroidListView11",
             "AndroidListView12",
             "AndroidListView13",
             "AndroidListView14",
             "AndroidListView15",
             "AndroidListView16",
             "AndroidListView17",

                                     };

     // Define a new Adapter
     // First parameter - Context
     // Second parameter - Layout for the row
     // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
     // Forth - the Array of data
     ArrayList<?> yourlist = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);

     // Assign adapter to ListView
     listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values));

     // ListView Item Click Listener
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition     = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

             // Show Alert 
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
               .show();

           }

      }); 
     myTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           }

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int count, int after) {
           }

           @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int before, int count) {

               MainActivity.this.my1(s);
               MainActivity.this.AndroidListView(s);
           }
          });

}
 private String my1(CharSequence arg) {

        String str = "";
        str = arg.toString().replace(" ", "  " ).replace("gold", "goldennnnnnn");
        this.myOuttext.setText(str);
          System.out.println(str);
        return str;
    }
        private String AndroidListView(CharSequence arg) {

    String AndroidListView = "";
    AndroidListView= arg.toString().replace(" ", "").replace("gold", "golderrrrrrrrr");
     this.et3.setText(AndroidListView);
      System.out.println(AndroidListView);
    return AndroidListView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code to change listView item at particular position:

```
ArrayList<?> yourlist = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
//            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values)); 



values[3] = "myNewItem";
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Response of above code is:
[image: Code_Response]

**EDIT:** To search a particular item and to change that:

```
for(int i =0; i<values.length; i++){
      if(values[i].equals("myNewItem")){
            values[i] = "A_Newer_One";
       }
 }
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

[image: New_Image]

Comment: **thanks for reply**.your reply is very helpfull & greate .i try it. my 80% coding is now complite.but i cant replace ** values[3] = "myNewItem"; ** **"gold" > "goldennnnnnn" **                **values[4] = "gold" > "golderrrrrrrrr"**

Comment: I didn't get your question. Can you be more clear about what you want in app? @marathapatil

Comment: I am still not getting. Just post what problem are you facing now? Text is not changing as you want or something else? @marathapatil

Comment: i want tochanged text  **a  >> aa,  b >>  bb,  c  >>  cc     and like gold  >>** **goldennnnnnn**

Comment: You can do one thing, just traverse the array to find out where is "gold" present and then change it to "goldennn" or whatever. Else there is nothing there for searching item in listView. You will have to make a new method for it and that would be kind of tricky. So better change the array's items and notify the adapter.

Comment: Updated answer. Please accept and upvote it if it solved your problem so that others could also get help from the accepted answer. :) @marathapatil

Comment: Thanks bro for upsate this ans.